# How to get details of a nested object in a serializer in DRF

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to create a serializer that would return a bunch of details of a 'Post' model in my project, but I want to get details of a nested object as well, the output of which I will show below:
**Post model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):

    # Base post attributes
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserOfApp, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    # Repost post attributes
    original_repost = models.ForeignKey(
        to="self",
        related_name="reposted_post",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    # Quote post attributes
    is_quote_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quoted_post = models.ForeignKey(
        to="self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    ...
```

**My serializer, using 'depth':**

```
class HomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id_str = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    ...
    quoted_post_id_str = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        depth = 2
        fields = "__all__"
```

This yields me an output like, the problem being it returns all sensitive data from my user model as well, like 'password' etc:

```
{
        "id": 16,
        ...
        "is_quote_post": false,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$180000$ni6drJvLjUU2$xoMt5tpJmz8TlmORfB/eTkYlGGpUGfriGz8rO7kVB8E=",
            "last_login": "2020-03-21T06:20:48Z",
            "is_superuser": true,
            "username": "manas",
            "first_name": "Manas",
            "last_name": "Acharekar",
            "email": "manas.acharekar98@gmail.com",
            "is_staff": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "date_joined": "2020-03-01T18:42:11Z",
            "dob": "1998-11-11",
            "gender": "M",
            "bio": "i own this place",
            "location": "",
            "website": "",
            "verified": true,
            "followers": [],
            "friends": [],
            "groups": [],
            "user_permissions": []
        },
        "original_repost": {
            "id": 1,
            ...
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$180000$ni6drJvLjUU2$xoMt5tpJmz8TlmORfB/eTkYlGGpUGfriGz8rO7kVB8E=",
                "last_login": "2020-03-21T06:20:48Z",
                "is_superuser": true,
                "username": "manas",
                "first_name": "Manas",
                "last_name": "Acharekar",
                "email": "manas.acharekar98@gmail.com",
                "is_staff": true,
                "is_active": true,
                "date_joined": "2020-03-01T18:42:11Z",
                "dob": "1998-11-11",
                "gender": "M",
                "bio": "i own this place",
                "location": "",
                "website": "",
                "verified": true,
                "followers": [],
                "friends": [],
                "groups": [],
                "user_permissions": []
            },
            "original_repost": null,
            "quoted_post": null
        },
        "quoted_post": null
    }
```

**My Serializer, without using depth:**

```
class HomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    id_str = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    ...
    quoted_post_id_str = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    quoted_post = PostSerializer()
    original_repost = PostSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
```

This outputs the posts properly, but I am not able to get the full nested object. In the return JSON mentioned below, I want to access **quoted_post.user** or **original_repost.user**, but only a foreign key is returned:

```
{
        "id": 16,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "followers_count": 0,
            "friends_count": 0,
            "username": "manas",
            "first_name": "Manas",
            "last_name": "Acharekar",
            "email": "manas.acharekar98@gmail.com",
            "date_joined": "2020-03-01T18:42:11Z",
            "dob": "1998-11-11",
            "gender": "M",
            "bio": "i own this place",
            "location": "",
            "website": "",
            "verified": true,
            "followers": [],
            "friends": []
        },
        "id_str": "16",
        ...
        "quoted_post": null,
        "original_repost": {
            "id": 1,
            ...
            "is_quote_post": false,
            "user": 1,
            "original_repost": null,
            "quoted_post": null
        },
        ...
        "is_quote_post": false
    }
```

How exactly do I solve this problem?

Comment: Use nested serializer

Comment: @ArakkalAbu how exactly do I do that? Can you post some relevant links please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, best is to modifying the PostSerializer().

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"

class HomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    id_str = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    ...
    quoted_post_id_str = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    quoted_post = PostSerializer()
    original_repost = PostSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
```

Also, I would recommend not to use ***__all__*** as it might reveal some unnecessary data.

Try to explicit defining the fields which you want to show

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["first_name","last_name" ]
```